# Ruby FTP sendcmd error

Tags: ruby, ftp

```
ftp = Net::FTP.new(IPAddress)
ftp.login(UserName, Password)
ftp.sendcmd("prompt")
ftp.sendcmd("mget filename*")
```

This code returns the following error.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:261:in `getresp': 500 'PROMPT': command not understood (Net::FTPPermError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:269:in `voidresp'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:292:in `block in voidcmd'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:190:in `mon_synchronize'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/ftp.rb:290:in `voidcmd'
```

Why is Ruby converting my command to UPPERCASE while I am giving it in lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think sendcmd is used this way. Try this alternative

```
require 'net/ftp'
user="user"
pass="password"
server="server"
Net::FTP.open(server) do |ftp|
    ftp.login(user,pass)
    ftp.nlst("filename.*").each do |file|
        ftp.getbinaryfile(file,file)
    end
    ftp.close
end
```